# Loop through hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

My search returns this hash bellow
    {"product"=>[{:title=>"It's All About Shoes Barbie Shoe Tree 2010 Hallmark Ornament"}, {:title=>"Iron Lady Bug Key Holder - Hide-A-Key"}]}

here is the loop and the code that generates the hash

```
id = "B003TM2IDS,B004X75EX4"
ids = id.split(',')

response = []
prod = Hash.new
product = Hash.new

#fetch product title from amazon
for aid in ids do
 res = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(aid, { :response_group => "ItemAttributes"})
 res.items.each do |item|
   prod[:title] = item.get("ItemAttributes/Title")
 end

 # hash
 product = {"product" => response.push(prod.dup)}
end

#loop to print the titles - Not working
product.each do |item_prod|
  puts item_prod.title
end
```

I do get the 
undefined method `title' for # (NoMethodError)

My question are:

- Is the Product hash correct?
- Is the loop correct?

I've done this millions of times but some reason I can't see the problem with this

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below:

```
product["product"].each do |prod| 
  puts prod[:title]
end
```

Comment: Good answer (but I think mine was before)

Comment: @Rafa really that was same argument Arup and Agis were having over the answer they both deleted, the question seemed simple enough, and I doubt it warrants a down vote, the down vote is used to express a wrong answer, 100 people would have answered the question same way

Comment: It is fine @bjhaid, I guess you did not realise about my answer before posting yours so I am not going to downvote for that. Anyway it is OP decision to accept the one he likes more.

Answer (score 1):

```
product["product"].each { |p| puts p[:title] }
```

Comment: Thanks! Also for the edit. I used to put the spaces, but I forgot.

Comment: Curiously my answer was the first correct one but other like mine has been accepted an with more votes!